# asterisk on an array in C

Tags: c

here is a question from a book I have which I don't understand

```
int ia[] = { 10, 12, 13 };
char ca[] = { ’a’, ’b’, ’c’ };
char st[] = "abc";
```

If i am not wrong, we have declared arrays of int and chars. But then the question asked to evaluate a few expression (answers included). I don't understand the following expressions:

```
(*ia)+1 => 11
*(ca+2) => c
*(st+3) => \0
```

I don't understand how this works. Isn't the asterisk using with pointers to deference them? or declare a pointer variable? What is it doing here? and how did those answers come to be?

Sorry I am very new to C

Comment: Read the part on pointer arithmetic.

Comment: It simply another way of subscripting an array using pointer arithmetic. `*(arr + 2)` is the same as `arr[2]`, and `*arr` is the same as `arr[0]`.

Comment: Yeah, please find a C tutorial or whatever you can understand and read it.  Pointers cannot be explained in a few paragraphs here.  And you *really* need to understand this stuff before you go much further.

Comment: @HotLicks i know what pointers. Just didn't know in the context of an array

Comment: Then you don't know pointers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array "decays" to a pointer to its first element in most expression contexts (the argument of sizeof is a major exception). These expressions are equivalent:

```
 *(a+b) === a[b] === b[a]
```

So

```
(*ia)+1 is ia[0]+1
*(ca+2) is ca[2]
*(st+3) is st[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(*ia)+1 => 11
```

That expression means the value at index 0 of the array **ia** which is 10 and then adds 1 to be 11. 
**ia** is the array name and also a pointer to the first element in the array, so (*ia) is simply the value pointed to by **ia** which is 10

```
*(ca+2) => c
```

That means, add 2 to the pointer pointing to the first element of the array **ca** and then get the value which is 'c'

Since **ca** is a character pointer, adding 2 will shift the pointer by 2 characters, so it is now pointing to 'c'

```
*(st+3) => \0
```

That expression shifts the pointer pointing to the first character in the array **st** by 3 so it reached the null terminating character.

Comment: awesome, makes a lot of sense now!